# Opening drop-down menu option with Javascript (OTRS)

Tags: javascript, otrs

I would like to open "nav-Customer" drop-down menu option with a Javascript command.

(There is no way to change source html file below)

```
<ul id="nav-People-container">
<li id="nav-Owner">
<a href="/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketOwner;TicketID=REDACTED" class="AsPopup PopupType_TicketAction"  title="Change the owner for this ticket">Owner</a>
</li>
<li id="nav-Responsible">
<a href="/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketResponsible;TicketID=REDACTED" class="AsPopup PopupType_TicketAction"  title="Change the responsible for this ticket">Responsible</a>
</li>
<li id="nav-Customer">
<a href="/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketCustomer;TicketID=REDACTED" class="AsPopup PopupType_TicketAction"  title="Change the customer for this ticket">Customer</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Trying with `document.getElementById("nav-Customer").click();` does not open the pop-up window that should activate upon mouseclick.

I tried this script with regular buttons, it works. but I need it in this specific case.

Can anyone help me? What am I not doing right?
(I have no Javascript experience)

Comment: Sorry I corrected my post I want to open "nav-Customer"...

Comment: Btw, it still does not work without the dash like this:
"document.getElementById("navCustomer").click();"

Comment: Also, I cannot change the source file, I am trying to make the Javascript work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('body').on('click', '#nav-Customer', function(e) {
      // do something after click
      // comment out to stop debug
      console.log("something was clicked");
      alert("You Clicked the Link");
    });
});
```

1. Check if document is ready.
2. onclick `#nav-Customer` do something.

Comment: Yes but what? I am way out of my league to figure it out.
Normally it opens a pop-up window with another interface with the link you can see below them...

"<a href="/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketCustomer;TicketID=REDACTED" class="AsPopup PopupType_TicketAction"  title="Change the customer for this ticket">Customer</a>"

Comment: I just want the script to simulate that I clicked on it. I don't want it to do anything else.

Comment: can you add all the code to the question, what code handles the popup ? There could be a problem on that code. Have you checked for errors in your console ?

Comment: i have updated my answer. try it and watch your console. when you click the link it will show you the text in your console.

Comment: I have updated it again to now show in the console as well as create a popup `alert();`

Comment: This is maybe what you are looking for:

https://pastebin.com/iVhTXwpB

Comment: btw, it generates nothing in console, I use Firefox. You mean F12 and console, right?

Comment: I tried it, and it just doesn't run.

What it does basically it combines the link with the domain name of the website and opens it up in a new window:
"https://examp.le/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketCustomer;TicketID=REDACTED"

Comment: you can try to do the same here, open any ticket, and then try to open the "Customer" option in the menu..

https://www.xpron.com/index.php/otrs-demo-system.html

Comment: where did you place my code in your page ?

Comment: I added it to an extension that runs your command when I press a specific key or key combination.

My goal is to create a keyboard shortcut that "presses" that button.